# Correct Keras/TensorFlow Activation Functions for simple numeric input/output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a input layer of 98 float values -5.0 < x < 5.0 and a single node float output with a value of -5.0 < x < 5.0

The dataset is very large at 10GB and can easily be expanded to a much larger size.

The part I am having most trouble with is the activation functions. With input and output values of -5.0 < x < 5.0 what would be the best activation functions to use.

Also if you have an idea of what type of neural net (LSTM, CNN), dropout, # of hidden layers, batch_size and optimizer are best to use for such a dataset, that would also be appreciated.

Despite the amount of examples and information out there, I am having quite a bit of trouble trying to get all these parameters correct for my dataset.

Comment: This is very broad question. Show your research first and kindly reduce the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, the part I am having the most trouble with is the activation functions. For strictly float inputs and outputs that go from -5 to 5 what activation functions should be used?

Comment: Kindly edit the question accordingly your above comment and it will sound much more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a manually stretched `'tanh'`.

Alone, 'tanh' returns from -1 to +1. You can stretch it multiplying it by 5 (or maybe just a little more, like 5.1, for instance).

```
model.add(YourLastLayer(..., activation='tanh'))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x * 5))
```

---

The other questions are impossible to answer, we have no idea of what your dataset is about, how data is organized, what it represents and what you want to achieve.

It seems, though, that it's a classical `Dense` (or fully connected) network case.